Jitsi Meet: How to add Multiple APP_SCHEME in interface_config.js (Its a React Native App)
I have two different apps for my JMS (Jitsi Meet Server). I want to add two different ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE in interface_config.js.
This will invoke any one of the app installed on the smartphone.
ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE: ‘com.brand.app1’,
ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE: ‘com.brand.app2’,
Now the problem is the interface_config.js only obeys the second ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE which in My case is ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE: ‘com.brand.app2’
What i am trying to achieve works on both iOS Apps because it uses same APP_SCHEME. But in android URL needs to have the target app package name.
I want to know how do you add two package names in interface_config.js? either or both are obeyed!
I tried adding two ANDROID_APP_PACKAGE but it didn't work. I expect either or both should work when there are two Identifiers in place
